# Check list size with a magic number (1) or global constant?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm in an argument with a co-worker about the following code:

```
private static final byte ONE_ELEMENT = 1;
private boolean isListSizeEqualsOne(List<MyClass> myList) {
    return myList.size() == ONE_ELEMENT;
}
```

I'm arguing that this kind of code admittedly reduces a warning about a magic number but unnecessarily increases clutter at the same time. I'm suggesting to inline the global variable instead:

```
private boolean isListSizeEqualsOne(List<MyClass> myList) {
    return myList.size() == 1;
}
```

Is there any literature for / against this example?

Comment: if the method name says that it is comparing to value one, then I don't think there is need for the constant.

Comment: If the intent is clear, then you don't need a constant.

Comment: Unless you have special meaning for the number that you are comparing, for instance, `int BAD_REQUEST=400`

Comment: I'm sure there are lots of articles on the internet but I can't name any atm. However whether to use constant or not might depend on whether you use that value once or more often and what should happen when you change it (should all code using it use the same updated value? etc.). In the context of a method named `isListSizeEqualsOne` I'd say the hard coded number (i.e. second snippet) is ok - I'd still ask myself why that method exists in the first place.

Comment: The second method is way better, I would ignore the warning, or do it like this: return myList.size() == new Integer(1); or maybe return equals(myList.size(), 1), where equals is your method

Comment: @Damiano `new Integer(1);` just to get rid of a warning? ouch. If you _really_ want to use something like that (and thus unneccessary unboxing) you should use `Integer.valueOf(1)` since that at least doesn't create a new object every time.

Comment: This probably belongs on the [code review site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). That being said, if this is the function in question, I honestly think it's just easier to write `myList.size() == 1;` everywhere instead of a wrapper call.

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc: Well, the advantage of the wrapper call is that the name of the call can indicate _why_ the size check is done (e.g. because a list of one element indicates an error somewhere). But this really depends on whether the reason for checking size==1 is always the same.

Comment: I'd recommend to use `if (!list.isEmpty() && (list.size() * list.size() == list.size()))`. But seriously, I wonder how long it takes until somebody comes up with something like this, just to shut up some arbitrary "warning". *"Rules are for the guidance of wise men and the obedience of fools."* (D. Bader)

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable comments. @Marco13's response really cracked me up, definitively going to give it a try :P

Comment: If all you want to do is check if the list size is one, check if the list size is one. You should aim to be concise and clear. If it's perfectly obvious in context why you're checking if the value is one, then just check if the value is one, don't make a freaking method or constant that obfuscates what's happening. To be clear, use `myList.size() == 1`. Having said that, if it's not clear in context why you're checking if it's one, then include a comment if this is the only place where you'll ever check it, or make a clearly named method if you'll use it elsewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem with the code is already in the method itself. Just like comments, a method name should not indicate what the code does, but *why*. In other words, it should indicate the functionality it provides, not its implementation.

That is, it should express the role that this method plays in the system. so instead of the name `isListSizeEqualsOne`, use a name that indicates the "why". For example `resultIsUnique`, or `errorReturned` (if you use an API where a list with a single element indicates an error).

Then the naming of the constant follows:

- `resultIsUnique`: constant `UNIQUE_RESULT_COUNT=1`
- `errorReturned`: constant `ERROR_RESULT_COUNT=1`

Finally, I don't think it is a good idea to enable warnings for inline constants. Using named constants for numbers only makes sense if either

1. the value must be the same everywhere (e.g. magic number for a file format), *or*
2. the value needs a name to be obvious, such as mathematical constants

If you need constants whose meaning is obvious (such as checking for an empty list by comparing the size to zero), then I think a plain inline value is perfectly ok.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and pointing out your personal opinion about warnings (which I share, btw).